# .htaccess query string blocking phpmyadmin

Tags: security, .htaccess

After phpmyadmin login,  I get this error message

```
Error in Processing Request
Error: 403
Error text: Forbidden"
```

I found that removing the following lines from .htaccess it doesn't give any error

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\"|%22).*(<|>|%3) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (javascript:).*(\;) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C).*script.*(>|%3) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\\|\.\./|`|=\'$|=%27$) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\;|\'|\"|%22).*(union|select|insert|drop|update|md5|benchmark|or|and|if) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (base64_encode|localhost|mosconfig) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (boot\.ini|echo.*kae|etc/passwd) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (GLOBALS|REQUEST)(=|\[|%) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

I already tried comment out the `RewriteCond %`  lines 1 by 1 to isolate the exact line,  but nothing happens unless I remove the entire block. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Administration panels are off-topic on Server Fault.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Apache 2.2 (you haven't specified), add this temporarily to your Virtual Host (or httpd.conf) configuration:

```
RewriteLog /tmp/rewrite.log
RewriteLogLevel 3
```

Then restart Apache and access the page then generates this error again. You can then trace the output in `/tmp/rewrite.log` to see which pattern exactly is being matched and resulting in the 403.

Comment: I'm using Apache 2.2.15, I have added 'RewriteLog /tmp/rewrite.log
RewriteLogLevel 3'

to the end of '/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf', restarted apache and checked '/tmp/rewrite.log', but the file is empty 0kb